# Can't get device token when distribution

Tags: ios, distribution, devicetoken

When in development, it works well, I can push notification to device.
but when distribution I can't get notification.

After debug I found the reason is that my server didn't receive device token from app.
I'm sure I used the correct provisioning and enabled the apps for both development and production.

anybody knows what's the reason that app can't get device token?